# INTERSECT and UNION giving different counts of duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, union, intersect

I have two tables A and B with same column names. I have to combine them into table C

when I am running following query, the count is not matching -

```
select * into C
from 
(
select * from A
union
select * from B
)X
```

The record count of C is not matching with A and B. There is difference of 89 rows. So I figured out that there are duplicates.
I used following query to find duplicates -

```
select * from A 
INTERSECT
select * from B

-- 80 rows returned
```

Can anybody tell me why intersect returns 80 dups whereas count difference on using union is 89 ?

Comment: use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` in your 1st query.

Comment: BTW I think you can simplify your query by getting rid of the outer wrapper and putting the "into" in the "select * from A" statement.  See example B: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

Comment: @M.Ali - Ali, I know that. I dont want to insert duplicates in table C. The point is not whether I must use union all or union. The point is that I am getting different number of duplicate rows when I run using intersect... and when I substract union all - union

Comment: Intersect removes duplicates too. So `a,a,a intersect a` will only return  1 row. Not three.

Comment: Intersect and Union does two different things, Intersect will return only matching rows in both tables, where as union will just get a single occurrence of each row from both tables.

Comment: I think Martin Smith got it right (though I don't have a sql-server at hand to test it). However, note the following two things that may explain what you see:
1. When you compare rows for determining distinct values, two NULL values are considered equal.
2. INTERSECT: Returns any distinct values that are returned by both the query on the left and right sides of the INTERSECT operand.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188055.aspx

Answer (score 4):

There are probably duplicates inside of `A` and/or `B` as well. All set operators perform an implicit `DISTINCT` on the result (logically, not necessarily physically).

Duplicate rows are usually a data-quality issue or an outright bug. I usually mitigate this risk by adding unique indexes on all columns and column sets that are supposed to be unique. I especially make sure that every table has a primary key if that is at all possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot @usr. I think the problem is that I am relying on INTERSECT and UNION to get the NUMBER of duplicate rows. Whereas INTERSECT will return me only that which is COMMON. UNION will return me rows which are NOT common. Neither of them may return me THE ACTUAL NUMBER of duplicate rows.

Comment: Reeya, that is correct.  To get the number of duplicate rows, use GROUP BY ... and HAVING COUNT(1) > 1. The GROUP BY can be all the columns, or if you know a unique set of columns, then use that. \